# Visual Studio Build task fails in Azure DevOps - my .Net Framework referenced project is .Net Core?

Tags: msbuild, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am seeing an issue when building in Azure DevOps on my own build VM. Same error occurs on a VS2017 hosted agent.

Building a csproj (happens when targeting the solution file too) of a .Net Framework 4.6.1 project. It has references to .Net Framework 4.6.1 projects.

In the build log I am seeing

> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1657,5): error : Project '..\MyNetFrameworkReferencedProject.csproj' targets 'netcoreapp2.1'. It cannot be referenced by a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1'. [C:\temp\vsts-2.150.2_work\10\s\TheNetFrameworkProjectIAmTryingToBuild.csproj
>   ]

Here is my build step

[image]

The same error occurs 5 times for each other .Net Framework 4.6.1 project reference

Nothing in the erroring projects packages.json suggest they are targeting any netcore packages

Any idea what I should check next?

Edit --

Running with debugging on I am seeing this error

```
##[debug]Exit code: 1
##[debug]Error record:
##[debug]Invoke-VstsTool : Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.
##[debug]At C:\temp\vsts-2.150.2\_work\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.151.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\InvokeFunctions.ps1:115 char:13
##[debug]+             Invoke-VstsTool -FileName $MSBuildPath -Arguments $argume ...
##[debug]+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
##[debug]    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
##[debug]    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Invoke-VstsTool
##[debug] 
##[debug]Script stack trace:
##[debug]at Invoke-Tool, C:\temp\vsts-2.150.2\_work\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.151.0\ps_modules\VstsTaskSdk\ToolFunctions.ps1: line 110
##[debug]at Invoke-MSBuild, C:\temp\vsts-2.150.2\_work\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.151.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\InvokeFunctions.ps1: line 115
##[debug]at Invoke-BuildTools, C:\temp\vsts-2.150.2\_work\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.151.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\InvokeFunctions.ps1: line 38
##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, C:\temp\vsts-2.150.2\_work\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.151.0\VSBuild.ps1: line 79
##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1
##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 22
##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 18
##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1
##[debug]Exception:
##[debug]Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException: Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.
##[error]Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.
```

I can take the MSBuild command minus the central logger and it will run successfully directly on the Build VM

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild.exe" "C:\temp\vsts-2.150.2_work\10\s\MyProject.csproj" /nologo /nr:false /p:Version=0.1.31 /p:OutputPath="bin\release" /p:platform="any cpu" /p:configuration="release" /p:VisualStudioVersion="15.0" /m /p:_MSDeployUserAgent="VSTS_AGUID_build_9_0"

Comment: Is there something that is unclear about the error message? You have incompatible references.

Comment: Hi @DanielMann, I appreciate the quick reply, is there an easy way to track them down? We are trying to move our builds to AZDO from TeamCity and have not seen this issue there

Comment: See my edit above, it is passing if I take the MSBuild command and run it directly on the VM

Comment: It's time to go home on Friday here but I think I may have uncovered the fix while tidying up another build

The presence of a variable called "targetFramework" causes Nuget to use that as the target for restoring packages...

2019-05-17T04:41:05.6580899Z Restoring packages for .NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0...

I will confirm and post some more details on Monday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

​I had a variable called "targetFramework" that I was using to track down where a Net Core API was being published as part of my build. The Nuget Restore task was picking up this variable and using it as a target and restoring the Net Core version of my packages.

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing a .NET Core (`netcoreapp2.1`) project from a .NET Framework project, which is not possible.

If you want to share code between .NET Core and .NET Framework, change the referenced project to .NET Standard instead (change `TargetFramework` to `netstandard2.0` in the csproj file).

Comment: I am not referencing any .Net Core projects or packages. One of the failing projects references a private Framework Nuget package, Octopack 3.0.53, and 6 project references that all target Framework 4.6.1

Comment: What are the contents of `MyNetFrameworkReferencedProject.csproj` from the error message? does it contain a `TargetFramework` tag?

Comment: Yeah, TargetFramework is set to 4.6.1. Also see my comment above, the Nuget restore task is picking up a "targetFramework" variable on the build pipeline set to "netcoreapp2.0". Renaming it to something else looks to have fixed it, will confirm with the build that prompted this post on Monday

Comment: Ah yeah a global property will affect all builds